# Laravel Not Saving Data on the database

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add users activity but I don`t know why the data is not saving. My table name is **activity_users** and the columns are *(id, player_id ,category_id,category_level , total_points, points_earned, success_percentage, created_at and updated_at)*.

Here`s my Model Code:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Player;
class ActivityUser extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['player_id', 'category_id', 'category_level', 'total_quiz_points', 'points_earned','success_percentage','updated_at'];

public function player() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Player::class);
}
```

}

Here`s my Controller Code:

```
    public function addUserActivity(Request $request)
{
     $WebKey = Setting::find(1)->api_secret_key;
     if($request->key==$WebKey){
        ActivityUser::create([
        'player_id'=>$request->player_id,
        'category_id'=>$request->category_id,
        'category_level'=>$request->category_level,
        'total_quiz_points'=>$request->total_quiz_points,
        'points_earned'=>$request->points_earned,
        'success_percentage'=>'100%',
        'updated_at'=>false,
    ]);
    $result['success'] = 'addUserActivity';
    $result['message'] = 'Users quiz activity has been added';
    echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        echo "You are not allowed to do that!";
    }
}
```

Comment: updated_at should be a timestamp.

Comment: Does it enter the if statement?

Comment: @geertjanknapen hi sir, I was able to fix it. The problem was not in the code. It was the table it self because I manually created it on mysql instead of using php artisan migrate

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes sir, I stop coding for almost a year :) and i just remembered it while i`m looking for the fix of my concern. thank you for your response sir

Comment: But this should have still worked if you specified a table name on your model. However it's good practice to just use migrations.

Comment: @geertjanknapen yeah it should, don``t know why. i was really stress that I could fix it while looking the problem on my code. Until I remembered the database migration in laravel. I`ve just tried it and I am not really sure if it will works but it suddenly works using the table i`ve created on database migration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem on my concern. The problem was not in my codes. The errors are from the table it self, because I created the table manually in myqsl instead of using database migration of laravel check the guide [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#creating-tables).